Indian passport holder - Schengen visa extension
Have you extended your Schengen visa before going into the country or from outside? What was the process?
We (M+F - Indian passport holders) got a schengen visa - validity - 1 July 2024 - 31st Dec 2024.
We were able to step outside in Zurich on July 19 2024 (first time we used our Schengen).
We are also going to Iceland and Amsterdam in Aug 2024.
We just realized our kid (US citizen) has a full 2 weeks off in Dec 21 - Jan 5 2025. It gets hard to travel when school is on, so we'd love to go back to Europe if possible as its a solid time when we can travel the country without the school being affected! (anything over 10 days otherwise can mean removal from the school, and summers are usually reserved for grandparents in India)
Total stay in Europe would be
July 2024 - 11 hours in Zurich
August 2024 - 1 week in Iceland (5 days)/Amsterdam (2 days)
Our visa expires Dec 31 2024 and was wondering if anyone has been able to extend their visa before they landed in the Sub continent? The articles speaking of visa extensions seems to be for those that are already in the country.
This article speaks of an extension for a late entry
https://www.immihelp.com/how-to-extend-schengen-visa/#:~:text=The%20decisions%20to%20approve%20Schengen,current%20visa%20is%20not%20expired.
"Late Entry
You must enter the Schengen area within the visa validity period and stay within that validity period (that is quite different from how US visa works, where visa stamp validity and authorized duration are two completely different things.)
For some reason, if you entered the Schengen area late, you may be able to apply for Schengen visa extension by that much of a duration. "
does anyone know about this? We just need an extension by 6-7 days in 2025 so we can do a trip in December --- Not sure if I need to apply for a new visa through a new application. Would anyone be able to help with this question?  In any case, it wont be possible to extend from within the country because it seems the process requires us to submit the passports and does not give an expectation of the number of days to process the extension (which will jeopardize our trip itinerary or possibly further delay us in case the extension takes time) and we may only be able to book a one-way ticket assuming to do this process we have to be within the country borders?
Thank you in advance for reading my query.
I also wrote to the local VFS office who is responsible for the visa application/Issuance, Ill let you know what they respond with.

The website you link to also says ‘determine if you have a justified reason’. IMHO just wanting to stay longer is vanishingly unlikely to be a ‘justified reason’.

You simply apply for a new visa for the visit in December/January.
The new visa will start the day after the old one ends.
Both visas would then cover the single visit.
